# SQL Question using join to get correct sum score

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, subquery, left-join

I Have 1 table named test_results

```
name | score | test results
=============================
A    | 10    |   pass
B    | 20    |   pass
C    | 10    |   fail
D    | 0     |   fail
A    | 20    |   pass
```

and  want to get the following results ordered by total score desc

```
name | total test number | time passed | total score
======================================================
A    |    2              |   2         | 30
B    |    1              |   1         | 20
C    |    1              |   0         | 10
D    |    1              |   0         | 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    name,
    count(*) total_test_number,
    count(*) filter(where test_result = 'pass') time_passed,
    sum(score) total_score
from test_results
group by name
```